# How to grab the values from a slider with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a slider that I grabbed from Codepen.io
here is the link to the slider I am using

https://codepen.io/dpdknl/pen/QggQRq

I want to grab the values of what the slider is displaying in the span so I can pass it to my jquery function. How could I grab that value? I am using an onchange event to send the value to the jquery function.

```
<div class="range" data-labels='["All", "18 - 21","22 - 29","30 - 39","40 - 49","50+"]'>
    <input name="range" type="range" id="rangeAge" min="0" step="1" max="100" value="0">
    <div class="range-output">
        <output class="output" name="output" for="range"><span></span></output>
    </div>
    <div class="label-container">
        <div class="left-label" style="display:none;"></div>
        <div class="right-label" style="display:none;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then I tried to grab them with this...

```
    $('#rangeAge').on('slidechange', function(){        
        var min = $('#rangeAge').slider().value();  
        alert(min);
    });
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Fiddle of current code

https://jsfiddle.net/NoJqueryMaster/d45envbu/3/

Comment: It's `slider().value()`, not `slider().val()`

Comment: Also I think at this point we need to see the JS where you initialized the slider. A jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: @NathanHawks Sorry, updated with .value() but still won't fire the onChange event or slideChange

Comment: Ok, ill try to put one together

Comment: @NathanHawks, here is a fiddle I put together of what I have so far.

Comment: I don't see the link

Comment: @NathanHawks, sorry, just added it to the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is accessible via:

```
$('#rangeAge').slider().value()
```

That's the general formula whenever you need to work with a modified element, meaning, anything to which you attach that JQuery-UI magic.

```
$(selector).widgetTypeName().methodInThatWidget()
```

Now that you know that, [here's the API docs for your specific case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

With events it's a little bit different. You have to pay attention to the examples they give on each widget's API page. For example, the slider's onChange event works like this:

```
$(selector).on('slidechange', callback)
```

Go forth and work that JQuery magic!

Comment: haha, thanks. @NathanHawks, I checked it out. It seems the issue is that I can't get the onChange event to fire. I think it might be the code for this slider affecting it. I'll go through it and see.

Comment: Use `$(selector).on('slidechange' callback)`

Comment: I had tried that but would not fire, i'll update with the code I tried

Comment: So I decided to go with a much smaller and easier slider than the other bulky one. This one works perfect for what i needed. Your code did work btw for getting the values that I needed for this new slider. Here is the codepen for anyone who might be looking for a good one.  https://codepen.io/glitchworker/pen/XVdKqj

Comment: Glad to hear it.